# Rails Form With Filepicker.io - Return URL of Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, filepicker.io

I'm making a form using `<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>`with filepicker.io in Rails and I have the line:

```
<%= f.filepicker_field :avatar_url%>
```

After the image is done loading, I want to use JavaScript to pipe the URL of the uploaded image from filepicker into an image tag in my code.  However, I can't seem to find where that URL is being added to the HTML code for submission in the form.  Does anyone know how to find that new image link, or if it doesn't get added to the HTML after being uploaded, how to return the new URL to the form for use with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on the [documentation](https://github.com/Filepicker/filepicker-rails), the image url is available in `@project.avatar_url`.

You need to check if the image is uploaded before the object is saved, if you want to display it before submitting the form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This does make sense. How would you check to see if the image is uploaded? If you have the time, would you be able to give me brief instructions on how to use @project.avatar_url with a javascript function? I've never seen this before and can't seem to find any documentation for it.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. From the documentation, it seems to me that using `filepicker_image_tag @project.avatar_url` assumes the string attribute has already been saved to the database. This method is for displaying the image elsewhere on the site. I don't understand what you mean by "You need to check if the image is uploaded before the objsect is saved, if you want to display it before submitting the form." Maybe elaborating on that would clarify for me how the helper can be used to display a preview in the form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 
`"onchange: 'onImageUpload()'"` 
event listener that will catch 'change' event
and at the function you will get

```
window.onImageUpload = ->
  file = event.fpfile
  img = $("<img>").prop("src", file.url)
  $(event.target).parent().append(img)
```

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#widgets-pick